# Java UDP client-server only works on one network

Tags: java, sockets, server, udp, client

Today I was writing some code that handles UDP communication so I can use it as a black-box in some projects, but I ran into some issues. It only worked when I opened the client on my home Wi-Fi network. I run the server code on a Linux VM from DigitalOcean. I've managed to replicate the same problem in this short code:

```
package udp;

import util.Util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConnectionTest {
 
    private static DatagramPacket createDatagram() { // packet size is 2^12
        return new DatagramPacket(new byte[Util.PACKET_SIZE], Util.PACKET_SIZE);
    }

    private static DatagramPacket createDatagram(String what, InetAddress address, int port) {
        if (what.length() > Util.PACKET_SIZE) {
            System.err.println("String too large for packet!");
            return null;
        }
        byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[Util.PACKET_SIZE];
        byte[] bytesUsed = what.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.arraycopy(bytesUsed, 0, bytesToSend, 0, bytesUsed.length);
        return new DatagramPacket(bytesUsed, bytesUsed.length, address, port);
    }

    public static void client() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket sck = new DatagramSocket(8888);
        sck.send(createDatagram("message from client",InetAddress.getByName("<server ip>"),8888));
        DatagramPacket p = createDatagram();
        sck.receive(p);
        System.out.println("Response came back!");
    }

    public static void server() throws IOException {
        DatagramSocket sck = new DatagramSocket(8888);
        DatagramPacket p = createDatagram();
        sck.receive(p);
        System.out.println("some message received from client at:");
        System.out.println(p.getAddress());
        sck.send(createDatagram("response",p.getAddress(),8888));
    }
}
```

Server launcher (I run it on the remote VM using IntelliJ Ultimate's built-in function):

```
package udp;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ConnectionTest_Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConnectionTest.server();
    }
}
```

Client launcher I run on my machine:

```
package udp;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ConnectionTest_Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ConnectionTest.client();
    }
}
```

First, I launch the server, then the client. The client sends a message to the server and the server actually always receives it regardless of the network.
Then it sends a response to the client, but for some reason the client never receives it, unless I run the client while being connected to one specific network (the one I use at home, 5 GHz). Other networks such as college Wi-Fi or an Android mobile hotspot never make it work.

I tried changing the packet size, re-sending the messages (in case the cause was packet loss), running the code on other machines but nothing worked.

Comment: I don't know, unless there's some address translation going on.  But I'd proceed by running wireshark at each end of the communication.

Comment: The server should not assume the clients port number: it should use the one in the request datagram. Easiest way to accomplish that is to reuse the request datagram for the response, just changing the data. I do t know why you’re calling this a connection test when it isn’t, or why the method is called createDatagram when it doesn’t.